# Can't instantiate instances of a class/model - Uninitialized Constant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class/model called AdditionalTime and ran the migration for creating it in the DB, however I can't create instances of AdditionalTime objects.

I get this NameError: uninitialized constant AdditionalTime whenever I try.

I initially discovered the problem when I tried to have another model's method create some of these objects, but I got the same error when testing it on the console.  I can create instance of my other models, just not AdditionalTime.

What might cause this to happen?

Edit: I'm using rails 4 and ruby 1.9.3

Thanks!

Comment: There are dozens of possibilities why this might happen - a few that come adhoc to my mind are 1) do you have a typo in the class, 2) is your file in an autoloaded directory (like app/models), 3) is your file called additional_time.rb, 4) ...

Comment: the file is in app/models, but the other models in that location are initializable and there is no typo in the file name or class declaration (additionaltime.rb)

Comment: additional_time.rb !!!

Comment: Thank you, I knew it had to be something silly!

Comment: You should use rails generators to create models and controllers to avoid those typos.